# Flag alert notifications, redux

Tags: discussion, flags

When posts have been flagged, I get an indicator that I can review these flagged posts:

[image: flagged post indicator]  <sup>(STEP 1)</sup>

Clicking on the highlighted number (in this case, the [image: there are new flagged posts; perhaps you can help]), allows me to see the flagged posts, where I'm presented with this set of options (in this case, the previous flagger had voted to delete):

[image: options for flagged post]   <sup>(STEP 2)</sup>

Perhaps I don't want to vote to delete the answer. That leaves the [image: <code>flag or disagree</code>] button, which, when clicked, takes me to this menu:

[image: last set of options]

> NOTE: *I asked a similar question earlier today, but it was closed as a duplicate, and, judging by the follow-on comments, I don't think I explained my issue very clearly. I'll try this one more time, rephrasing my question*.

Let's assume that, for some reason, I want to take no action; that is:

- I don't want to vote to delete the question,
- I don't feel a need to reflag the question, and
- I don't want to disagree with the flag,

**Here is what is prompting my question: Because there is no option to "Ignore" (or "Pass" or "Abstain" or "Take No Action"), when I go back to the Stack Exchange site, it looks the same as it did before:**

[image: flagged post indicator]

**I would prefer instead that it look like this:**

[image: no unreviewed flags]

Sure, I can just ignore that alert, but, it seems like it should be gone. After all, even if I decided to take no action, I still reviewed the flagged post. Had I "piled on," and voted to delete, or flagged the question as being low quality, the [image: there are new flagged posts; perhaps you can help] would disappear. However, because I've opted to do nothing, it stays there. It seems like there ought to be a way for the notification counter to be reset, without voting to delete, reflagging the question, or disagreeing with the existing flags.

I've always regarded that yellow number as being akin to the unread message counter in my email inbox. Just like my email tells me how many messages are unread, this number tells me how many flagged posts need to be reviewed. For example, if it starts at [image], and I take action on two posts, the alert changes to [image: there are new flagged posts; perhaps you can help]. However, there doesn't seem to be any way to reset the counter, not unless I either flag, vote, or disagree with each and every flag.

I realize this is a minor issue, but consider this: if I log back on a couple hours later, and the screen still looks like this:

[image: flagged post indicator]

there is no way to tell, just by looking at it, if that's the same post I've already examined, or if that previously-reviewed post has already been handled by a moderator, and now there's a new flagged post.

Comment: This is also annoying on Stack Overflow, where you wish to ignore certain flags. When you head back to the queue to see more recent flags, the flags you chose to ignore from earlier are mixed in with the new flags as well.